# Find which group has highest percent breach

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find out which group from the domain column has the highest percent breach.

I've tried using groupby. Where I want create another df and store the sum of value for Breach and Meet there.But, I don't know how to store the sum of value onto the new dataframe for breach and meet.

```
new_df2 = new_df.groupby('Domain')['Breach'].sum()

   ID   Domain    Breach  Meet
0  A1  Finance      4       6
1  B1  Finance      5       3
2  C1       IT      2       3
3  D1       IT      7       3
```

Output should in new dataframe:

```
   Domain  Breach  Meet   %Breach   %Meet
0  Finance    9     9       50%      50%
1  IT         9     6       60%      40%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `groupby` then using `concat` after adjust the out put

```
s=df.groupby('Domain').sum()
s=pd.concat([s,s.div(s.sum(1),axis=0).mul(100).astype(str)+'%'],1)
Out[138]: 
        Breach Meet Breach   Meet
Domain                           
Finance      9    9  50.0%  50.0%
IT           9    6  60.0%  40.0%
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make the Breach and Meet column in percentage format?